# Snowflake-Snowsight: Not able to delete folder

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Could someone share your thoughts about deleting folder in snowflake-snowsight? I have few folders created in snowsight,I wanted to delete one of the folder but not able to. I deleted all the worksheets from the folder(now folder is empty) but still I don't see any option to delete the folder? any thoughts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on worksheet (left menu) => Your empty folder in right big area => click on arraow against your folder name => Click delete. Refer image below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Pankaj, I am able to delete now.

Comment: Thanks too. FWIW, I didn't think the UI is that ovious. When you're in a particular worksheet and have the treeview to your left, the only options are New worksheet and rename